# How do i apply sql like query on the aws cli table output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How do i apply sql like query on the aws cli table output.
My aws cli command is as follows:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{ImageId: ImageId, InstanceId: InstanceId, InstanceType: InstanceType,State: State.Name, KeyName : KeyName,AZ: Placement.AvailabilityZone,Tenancy: Placement.Tenancy,LaunchTime: LaunchTime, PrivateIpAddress: PrivateIpAddress, PublicIpAddress: PublicIpAddress, VpcId: VpcId, SubnetId: SubnetId, Architecture: Architecture,SG: SecurityGroups[0].GroupName,SG_ID: SecurityGroups[0].GroupId,OwnerID: NetworkInterfaces[0].OwnerId}' --region us-east-1 --output table
```

I want to do the following on the above aws cli query table output:

I want to group all the InstanceId by instance type as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                                                                                                                                     DescribeInstances                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+------------+---------------+------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+----------+----------------+
|     AZ     | Architecture  |        ImageId         |     InstanceId       | InstanceType  |   KeyName   |        LaunchTime         |    OwnerID    | PrivateIpAddress  | PublicIpAddress  |                                                  SG                                                    |         SG_ID         |    State    |    SubnetId      | Tenancy  |     VpcId      |
+------------+---------------+------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+----------+----------------+
|  us-east-1b|  x86_64       |  ami-1ecae776          |  i-dad4180f          |  t2.micro     |  TruCentric |  2015-09-08T15:27:59.000Z |  401331319872 |  10.51.1.232      |  None            |  build-vpc-BastionSecurityGroup-1RRONL28DLJAM                                                          |  sg-6d476b0a          |  stopped    |  subnet-1d323d6a |  default |  vpc-4976b12d  |
|  us-east-1a|  x86_64       |  ami-1ecae776          |  i-e8c2614b          |               |  TruCentric |  2015-09-08T15:27:59.000Z |  401331319872 |  10.51.0.209      |  None            |  build-vpc-BastionSecurityGroup-1RRONL28DLJAM                                                          |  sg-6d476b0a          |  stopped    |  subnet-b8a3f793 |  default |  vpc-4976b12d  |
|  us-east-1a|  x86_64       |  ami-d05e75b8          |  i-d4cc6f77          |               |  acquia_ops |  2019-07-15T15:34:59.000Z |  401331319872 |  10.51.0.220      |  52.91.20.69     |  build-vpc-ApplicationSecurityGroup-81J8RJLV25JH                                                       |  sg-6e476b09          |  running    |  subnet-b8a3f793 |  default |  vpc-4976b12d  |
|  us-east-1a|  x86_64       |  ami-d05e75b8          |  i-3c43ef9f          |               |  acquia_ops |  2016-04-23T23:13:14.000Z |  401331319872 |  10.52.0.85       |  54.165.202.171  |  dev-vpn-SecurityGroup-U7UONIX6LIB9                                                                    |  sg-67f9d100          |  running    |  subnet-48124563 |  default |  vpc-21d71145  |
```

Comment: I was going to propose that you consider using [lebinh/aq](https://github.com/lebinh/aq) which allows you to query AWS resources using SQL but it seems [broken at present](https://github.com/lebinh/aq/issues/8) though you might be able to get it to work with some Python package version management tweaks.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. What do you mean by "group all the InstanceId by instance type"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by 'group by' you mean to list the entries of a particular InstanceType together i.e. sorted by, the below command should be able to get you the output you need, although the InstanceType is repeated and not blank per the output your showed in the questions.

It uses the `sort_by` function in the `--query` of the AWS CLI commands.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'sort_by(Reservations[].Instances[], &InstanceType)[:].{ImageId: ImageId, InstanceId: InstanceId, InstanceType: InstanceType,State: State.Name, KeyName : KeyName,AZ: Placement.AvailabilityZone,Tenancy: Placement.Tenancy,LaunchTime: LaunchTime, PrivateIpAddress: PrivateIpAddress, PublicIpAddress: PublicIpAddress, VpcId: VpcId, SubnetId: SubnetId, Architecture: Architecture,SG: SecurityGroups[0].GroupName,SG_ID: SecurityGroups[0].GroupId,OwnerID: NetworkInterfaces[0].OwnerId}' --region us-east-1 --output table
```

Does this help?

Comment: This just sorts the result and we cannot group the instances with instance type.
I checked a lot and didn’t  find a direct way in aws cli, so I tried to parse the obtained result via json python library and achieved the required.

Comment: Understood, when you group you usually add an aggregate field such as sum, avg. Was wondering if you had such an aggregate, I did not see that in the output shown.  Or are you trying to mimic a 'select distinct' result across all the fields in the output table? Parsing the results in Python is certainly another way to solve this.